# Set Release.ReleaseDescription automatically from the build. (Azure devops Pipeline)

Tags: azure-devops

Good afternoon, I need help with this case, I want to generate a release description in my pipeline builds, I tried to set the variable in the build and I used a group variable but I was not successful, the idea is to generate a build that contains a description of what contains and when generating the new release already has the value in the variable Release.ReleaseDescription, I have a slack task that sends approvals, it would be good to have this description so that the people who approve see what it contains. This manual procedure is currently performed when the release is generated and a description is placed.

Answer (score 0):

Variable group can only share variables with static values from build pipeline to release pipeline. However there is an extension task tool **[Variable Tools for Azure DevOps Services](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.variablehydration)** that can accomplish this. You can follow below steps:

1, You need first to search for **Variable Tools for Azure DevOps Services** and install it to your organization.
This task include two subtasks as the task describles:.

**Variable Save Task** - During your build you can save the variables to a json file stored with your other build assets

**Variable Load Task** - During your Release you can load the saved variables and gain access to them.

2, Then you need to define a variable (BuildDescription)in your build pipeline
[image]

3, Add a powershell task to assign a value to variable BuildDescription.

[image]

4, add Variable Save Task to save variable BuildDescription to a json file and store it to the build artifacts folder which will be published to azure devops server as a part of aritfacts.

[image]

5, in the release pipeline, add task Variable Load Task, and then you can use the variable (BuildDescription) in your release pipeline.
[image]

**Update**:
As above tasks cannot be run on linux system. We can write bash scripts to do the variable save task and variable load task.

To save the variable, you only need to replace above variable save task with bash task to run below command.

```
echo '{"des":"description"}' > variable-meta.json
```

To load the variable. Add bash task to replace variable load task

```
val= ($(jq '.description' variable-meta.json))

echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildDescription]$val"
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, the extension task tool Variable Tools for Azure DevOps Services only works for windows, the pipeline for both build and release is running on linux, I have tried several extensions and I have the same problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: You achieve what above tasks do with bash scripts. The main idea is to save the defined description variable to json file. And read the variable from the json file in release pipeline, and set variable to the environment variable you defined. Please check above updates:

Comment: Hi, Did you try writing your own bash scripts? How did it go, Any updates?

Comment: hello, thanks for the information, do what you told me, the same did not work for the variable Release.ReleaseDescription, at the moment I did a task that sends an email with sendgrid and places the value of that variable in the approval mail, the main idea is that within the slack Azure Pipeline App take the value of Release.ReleaseDescription.
 0